# Photoshop - How to apply an indexed color palette when saving individual slices using "Save for Web"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I'm basically trying to optimize "Save for Web & Devices" in Adobe Photoshop for pixel art.

What I want is to apply an indexed color palette to all the individual images saved when using the slicing tool and "Save for Web". Instead I'm given all my image slices with huge color palettes. Any help would be appreciated on how this is correctly done.

Comment: does each image need it's own palette or are all images encompassed in one palette?

Answer (score 1):

See an image with screenshots [over here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwjoI.jpg).

As you see, when working with indexed colors, all separate slices already have a separate color palette. If you want to use a specific, predefined palette, you can load it from the menu as shown.

[image]